# Add SQL table CHECK using sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to add this CHECK in one of my tables. I am using Sequelize in a node.js api running on Postgres DB.

```
CHECK (
    (
        CASE WHEN UserID         IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        + CASE WHEN TableID      IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        + CASE WHEN FoodID       IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        + CASE WHEN RestaurantID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        + CASE WHEN CategoryID   IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        + CASE WHEN ShipID       IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    )
    = 1
)
```

So, I need the database to enforce the check on the table where one of those columns must be not null, and only one, the others must be null.

Is there a way to do that in Sequelize?

I tried doing this:

```
let sql = `ALTER TABLE TestTable
ADD CONSTRAINT check_test CHECK testBool=false;`
await sequelize.query(sql, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW });
```

I just created TestTable with a testBool column just to test things out to see if they would run at all.

When that runs I get this ERROR:

```
relation "testtable" does not exist
```

I don't understand why the name is all lowercase. In the model definition I even have the:

```
freezeTableName: true
```

I can see the Table in the DB, I can save rows to it etc... so, it's there.

Comment: Use a raw SQL query in a sequelize to execute a SQL-statement that creates the check in a DB. You can place it in a migration file if you use migrations to alter a DB according to changes in models.

Comment: Independently of Sequelize: your SQL can be simplified to `check (  (num_nonnulls(userid, tableid, foodid, restaurantid, categoryid, shipid) = 1) )`

Comment: `"TestTable"`<> `TestTable` don't use the dreaded quoted identifiers   https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: You saved me from a massive mess @a_horse_with_no_name. Thank you! I just tested the RAW approach using the naming conventions you linked to here... seems to work. I'll test more and make sure it's all good.

Answer (score 0):

From the feedback I got in the comments:

1. use the sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW
2. follow proper naming conventions [Postgres naming rules](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names)

3. run this query worked:

```js
    let sql = 'ALTER TABLE test_table ADD CONSTRAINT check_test CHECK testBool=false';

    await sequelize.query(sql, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW });
```