# Add SQL CHECK constraint with Sequelize at model definition without having to ALTER table afterwards?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

So, I am able to add a CHECK constraint like this:

[ALTER TABLE with sequelize RAW query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61214694/add-sql-table-check-using-sequelize?noredirect=1#comment108294224_61214694)

```
let sql = `ALTER TABLE TestTable
ADD CONSTRAINT check_test CHECK testBool=false;`
await sequelize.query(sql, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW });
```

What I want to do is be able to make that part of the model definition in my Sequelize models.
I am running that query because I do not know how to make an SQL check of that type part of the model definition.

I am not sure what the best way to go about that is. When the models sync, I want the them to sync with the CHECK in place already, no further migration.

Is this something I need to run in the model hooks somewhere? like afterSync?

Comment: Yes, you can define your checks inside `beforeCreate` hook.

Comment: I’ll try that. And see. I have put the checks into the afterSync hook. It works, but if I sync on a table where those checks are already in, it logs errors  so, the afterCreate seems to be the proper place. I’ll see how it goes. Thank you.

Comment: beforeCreate has the same problem afterSync has, meaning, it does add the check to the table, but it runs every time I insert a user and as beforeCreate runs before inserting any user, it errors with "MergeWithExistingConstraint" because that check is already on the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `beforeCreate` sequelize hook to add checks before inserting any record.

```
{
 hooks: {
        beforeCreate: (user, options) => {
          user.UserId = user.UserId ? 0 : 1
          user.TableId = user.TableId ? 0: 1
          user.UserId = user.UserId ? 0 : 1
          user.TableId = user.TableId ? 0: 1
        },
}
```

You can also skip something to be inserted if not in desired format.

```
  user.UserId = user.UserId > 10 : user.UserId : undefined
```

It will run every time you try to insert a row in the table. It's actually running your defined conditions before inserting the data in the table. 
Here, you are just modifying the data that is to be inserted based on conditions .

Comment: What I am looking for is a way to add the SQL check in the SQL table definition... I want sexualize to push the ALTER TABLE check to Postgres so that sequelize doesn't have always check before every insert. I want it to be part of the TABLE definition so Postegres will enforce validation regardless of Sequelize's logic.

Comment: I don't know if it will work, I haven't tried ever. But worth having a look here https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html#instance-method-addConstraint